# Is it possible to add additional services to an existing Microsoft 365 E5 Developer subscription?

Tags: microsoft365-defender

I am trying to create a lab to test out some deployment scenarios for MS Defender and Intune. I have a Microsoft 365 E5 developer subscription [Microsoft 365 E5 Developer (without Windows and Audio Conferencing)]. This subscription is available to me via my MSDN subscription benefits that my employer pays for. I would like to add "Enterprise Mobility + Security E5" and "Microsoft Defender for Endpoint P2" products.

1. Is this possible? If yes, what's the best way to do this?
2. Can I charge these addons to my personal credit card?
3. Will I have full control over these services? Basically, I want to make sure that I can add / remove devices without affecting my employer's tenant or it affecting what I want to do?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to add additional services to an existing Microsoft 365 E5 Developer subscription. You can add "Enterprise Mobility + Security E5" and "Microsoft Defender for Endpoint P2" products to your existing subscription by using the Microsoft 365 admin center.

You can charge these addons to your personal credit card if you are paying for them personally. However, if your employer is paying for the subscription, it would be best to check with them.
Once done, you will have full control and can add or remove devices without affecting your employer's tenant or your own work.